# Securing data passed between two sites via a browser

Tags: encryption

I need to pass some data securely from one web site to another via a browser.

A user visits site A and clicks a link there which takes him to site B; this could be just a link which would produce GET request or a submit button of a form, which would produce POST, either is fine. The communication is other HTTPS.

Some data is sent with the request. Data is not long, up to 20 symbols. I need to make sure that nobody but site A and B can understand it, not even the user who is operating the browser.

I am also thinking that I might want to get site A to sign data, but I am not sure if I really need this. Technically for me it is not a problem to share the key between these 2 sites.

The value that I need to secure is just a user name. I am thinking just about encrypting it with AES algorithm using 256 bit key on site A and decrypting it on site B with the same key. I am not planning to use any kind of salt.

The questions is can the approach I am thinking about be considered somewhat secure or is it very vulnerable?

Comment: There are many possible answers based in the info you've given us.i don't see how we can answer without a better understanding of the requirements

Comment: Sure, the simplest implementation would be the best solution for me from many possible options that you talk about. Is there anything in particular I should add to make my question clearer?

Comment: Too much questions in a single query?? :(

Comment: @AnkitGupta In that case I would appreciate a general answer that would cover some basics and things to consider in general, maybe explain some options, and from there I would dig deeper with more specifics.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Thanks for your responses. It looks like the way I asked the question initially was not clear enough so I have updated it. I would very much appreciate if you could have another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to pass some data securely

What do you mean exactly by *"securely"*, do you mean that:

- You do not want the user to be able to read the content of the protected data (ie. you want to ensure the data *confidentiality*),
- You do not want the user to be able to tamper or forge the data (ie. you want to ensure the data *integrity*)?

By simply encrypting the data, you solely ensure the data confidentiality. Without knowing the key, a malicious user could still try to modify the encrypted data to try, for instance, to get access to another user's data.

If you want to ensure the data integrity, you do not need asymmetric signatures (it would work, but as you feel it would be overkill), what you need is to apply an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) to the data. Thanks to this, given a common secret, website B will be able to check that the data allegedly received from website A is indeed authentic.

From then the fact that you want to apply a cryptographic function on top of this to hide the data content is totally up to you. The data could perfectly stay in clear form without reducing the security of the HMAC as an integrity protection system.

Comment: The contents of the data is a user id. Anybody who provides this data to website B, will be logged in as that user. I thought that by just encrypting the data I could ensure that a) it can only be read by website B and A b) it cannot be tempered (because malicious user would not know how to encrypt message correctly) c) it comes from the website A (again, because 3rd parties would not know how to encrypt the message correctly). But now that you mention the integrity, I kind of start to understand that it will be necessary to do hash check to ensure that I decrypted it correctly.

Comment: In the end I have decided to pass to website B 2 values. One is user id encrypted with symmetric key algorithm and the other is HMAC of unencrypted user id. This will make sure all the 3 requirement I mentioned in my previous reply are met. I think this is in line with your answer, but I would appreciate if you could tell me if I have got something wrong or missing something.

Comment: @KirillG. Yes, it's quite correct. To get the best security however, I would recommend to calculate the HMAC of the encrypted value you want to protect (the encrypted user ID in this case) instead of the plaintext one. For more information about why this is better, you can find an interesting discussion here: [Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/23581)